# 100 random numbers with an odd and even counter

Tags: python, counter

I have the following assignment:

> In this chapter you saw an example of how to write an algorithm that determines whether
>   a number is even or odd. Write a program that generates 100 random numbers, and keeps
>   a count of how many of those random numbers are even and how many are odd.

This is how far I've been able to get, I can get the 100 numbers, but I can't figure out how to total up the odd and evens. This is supposed to include a value returning boolean function as well.

All we're allowed to use is loops, if-elif-else, functions, and other basic things.

```
import random

NUMBER_LIST = [random.randint(0,1000)]

def main():

    for numbers in range(100):

        number = print(NUMBER_LIST)
        number

    is_even(number)

    print('The total amount of even numbers is', even_count)
    print('The total amount of odd numbers is', 100 - even_count)   

def is_even(number):

    even_count = 0

    for number in NUMBERS_LIST:
        if (number % 2):
            even_count += 1

    return even_count

main()
```

EDIT:
I'm not supposed to use a List, so if theres a way to do it without, let me know!

Comment: Why do you need to keep a list of the numbers? Also, they can only be either odd or even, so you don't need to track both.

Comment: http://www.learnr.pro/content/19360-starting-out-with-python-2nd-edition-gaddis-series/255#418778195:96034.13064032793

Comment: Is `is_even` a test to see if a number is even or not, or is it counting the number of even values?

Comment: I don't know how to allow the loop function to go through the list of numbers

Comment: `NUMBERS_LIST` in the for loop in `is_even()` needs to be `NUMBER_LIST`. Also, your if statements do not need brackets, the if statement should be in `main()` so you dont need to loop twice, and you aren't doing anything with the return value of `is_even()`, `number` is not a statement, you can remove it.

Comment: It should be checking if it is even, and if it is, adding it to the total of even numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def main():
    numberList = []  # create an empty list, to add 100 random ints to
    for i in range(100):
        numberList.append(random.randint(1,1000))  # add a random int

    # now, numberList has 100 random numbers in it

    # keep track of how many odd numbers
    oddCount = 0

    # loop through numberList
    for number in numberList:
        if number%2 == 1:  # number is odd
            oddCount += 1

    evenCount = 100 - oddCount  # if a number is not odd, it is not even

    print("There are", oddCount, "odd numbers, and", evenCount, "even numbers")
```

Okay, now that we have that hard-coded version, let's try a more flexible way that allows you to specify as many things as possible:

```
def main(numNumbers, smallestNumber, biggestNumber):
    numberList = []
    for i in range(numNumbers):
        numberList.append(random.randint(smallestNumber, biggestNumber))
    oddCount = 0
    for number in numberList:
        if number%2:  # oh look, I didn't have to do the `== 1` part
            oddCount += 1
    evenCount = numNumbers - oddCount
    print("There are", oddCount, "odd numbers, and", evenCount, "even numbers")
```

Comment: I would recommend using `def main(numbers=100):` and then referencing `numbers` in the method body rather than hardcoding it so it can be extended.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

NUMBER_LIST = [random.randint(0,1000)]
even = 0;
odd = 0;
for numbers in range(100):
    if (numbers%2 == 1):
        odd = odd+1
    if (numbers%2 == 0):
        even = even+1
print('number of evens is: ',even)
print('number of odds is: ',odd)
```

So you can just do this sort of thing.

Comment: You only need to count even or odd numbers, the other can be found by the 100 - [even or odd]. The remainder is the value of the other. It would save you an if statement.

Comment: That's true but copying and pasting the if statement was just too tempting and easy

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a list, but let's do that since your problem may require so.

First of all, note that your code just creates a list with one random number inside it. If you want to populate the list with 100 random numbers, you must do something similar to this:

```
NUMBER_LIST = []
i = 0
while i < 100:
    number = random.randint(0, 1000)
    NUMBER_LIST.append(number)
    i += 1
```

Then, you check if the number is even, with `number % 2 == 0` (That is, the remainder of the division of number by 2 is 0. this will return either true or false) and increment the respective counter:

```
NUMBER_LIST = []
# initialize both counters
evens = 0
odds = 0
i = 0
while i < 100:
    number = random.randint(0, 1000)
    NUMBER_LIST.append(number)
    if number % 2 == 0:
        evens += 1
    else:
        odds += 1
    i += 1
```

Then, you just need to print the counts:

```
print("The number of even numbers is: " + evens)
print("The number of odd numbers is: " + odds)
```

The full code would then be:

```
import random
NUMBER_LIST = []
evens = 0
odds = 0
i = 0
while i < 100:
    number = random.randint(0, 1000)
    NUMBER_LIST.append(number)
    if number % 2 == 0:
        evens += 1
    else:
        odds += 1
    i += 1
print("The numbers were: " + str(NUMBER_LIST))
print("The number of even numbers is: " + evens)
print("The number of odd numbers is: " + odds)
```

And without the list:

```
import random
evens = 0
odds = 0
i = 0
while i < 100:
    number = random.randint(0, 1000)
    if number % 2 == 0:
        evens += 1
    else:
        odds += 1
    i += 1
print("The number of even numbers is: " + evens)
print("The number of odd numbers is: " + odds)
```

Comment: I'm not actually supposed to use a list, I just saw other people doing it with a similar assignment and i followed. It'd be awesome if you could show me how to do it with no list!

Comment: @RussellSherrill This code barely even uses the list except for printing the numbers chosen :) Just remove the declaration, the `append` line and the first print.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
def main(n=100):
    NUMBER_LIST = [random.randint(0,1000) for x in range(0,n)]
    odds = len(list(filter(lambda x: x % 2, NUMBER_LIST)))
    print("Odd Numbers: {}\nEven Numbers: {}".format(odds, n-odds))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randrange

even = 0
for i in range(100):
    num = randrange(1000)
    if num % 2 == 0:
        even += 1

print('There were {0} even numbers and {1} odd numbers.'.format(even, 100-even))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same class! This code worked for me.

```
import random

def main ():

    counter = 1
    even_numbers = 0
    odd_numbers = 0
    while counter < 101:

        a = random.randint(1,100)


        if a % 2 == 0:
            even_numbers += 1
        else:
            odd_numbers += 1
        counter += 1

    if counter == 101 :
        reveal_total(even_numbers, odd_numbers)

def reveal_total(even_numbers, odd_numbers):
    print("This many evens : ", even_numbers)
    print("This many odds : ", odd_numbers)

main()
```